# How to fix the gap between logs when restarting ConfigNode in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Why did Apache IoTDB report IllegalStateException error when restarting ConfigNode? The error message is stated `Found a gap between logs: the last log segment log-79627_94959 ended at 94959 but the next log segment log_inprogress_120859 started at 120859`. I checked and seems no relevant questions to this error were asked. What may be the reason for this log gap, and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because part of the time series data in Apache IoTDB was accidentally deleted. I checked github and this bug seems to be fixed in 2023. (https://github.com/apache/ratis/pull/801) . Are you using a low IoTDB version? It is recommended to upgrade to Version 1.3 as soon as possible. At present, you can find the corresponding file directory, delete all logs before `120859`, and then restart.